# Activity report shows 490 records but storage Usage report shows 763,000 records

Tags: salesforce, storage

We are trying to free Storage Usage by reducing Tasks and Events related to inactive users. Only 490 Activities are present still in the Storage Usage report we see over 763,000 records of Events which is 1.5GB. Question is, what is contributing to 1.5GB of Events and where to find them so that I can remove unwanted records to free space?

Answer (score 0):

You might be a victim of "[archived activities](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?language=en_US&type=5&id=sf.activities_archived.htm)".

You can query them as if they're in Recycle Bin:

- via API (including developer console's query editor and Workbench) you typically tick "include deleted records" or something because it's a query() vs [queryAll()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_queryall.htm), different API call
- in Apex you can put [`ALL ROWS`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_query_all_rows.htm) at the end of the query.

[image: "workbench" utility with selected option to include deleted/archived records]

Do a quick and dirty check like `System.debug([SELECT COUNT() FROM Task LIMIT 50000 ALL ROWS]);` and see what happens?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I ran this query and got count as 50,000 even though the Tasks and Events report shows 489 records. I tried the query for limit upto 700,000 records and got count as 700,000, beyond this, it gets very slow.
Does that mean we have more than 700,000 Events in Org?
I have emptied My recycle bin and Org recycle bin, this did not help at all.
How do you suggest I get rid of these unwanted Activities related to any inactive user?
Any help is appreciated..

Comment: You should be able to just export the Ids with that query, maybe with some form of `WHERE OwnerId IN (...)`. And then delete from apex, data loader, whatever. You seen https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000325075&type=1 and https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008m6IIAQ ?